# Google Map Api and JS code not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

Below is my simple code getting the distance from point A to point B (Array of Addresses). The problem lies "`alert(end[i]+distanceKM);`" especially the variable, distanceKM.

I think I did it right. Variable, distanceKM, was declared outside of the for loop and the value is set with in the for loop. And my alert is inside the for loop.

But I am still getting

Alert values: 4700 Highway 280undefined and so on....

Seems like distanceKM has not been set, = undefined, which I have: distanceKM=response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;

Test code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Distance Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    }

    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value.split('@@');
        var distanceKM;         
        for (i = 0; i < end.length; i++) 
        {
            var request = {
                origin:start, 
                destination:end[i],
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
                {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    distanceKM=response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
                }
            }); 
            alert(end[i]+distanceKM);   
        }

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="start">Start: </label>
            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="815010 NE 36th Steet, Redmond, WA, USA" />

            <label for="end">End: </label>
            <input type="text" name="end" id="end" value="4700 Highway 280, Birmingham, AL, USA@@6900 US Highway 90, Suite 2, Daphne, AL, USA@@549 Brookwood Village, Homewood, AL, USA@@4800 Whitesburg Dr., Huntsville, AL, USA" />

            <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
            <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The route request does not return a result synchronously, so if you try to access distanceKM immediately outside the request, it is still undefined.

To help you get a sense of the execution order, see the numbered comments:

```
    // 1.) route request is sent, and the anonymous callback
    //     function is defined.
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
    {
        // 3.) Response from google is received and the anonymous 
        //     callback function is called.
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            // 4.) distanceKM is set.
            distanceKM=response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
        }
    });
    // 2.) Alert is shown
    alert(end[i]+distanceKM);
```

So, to get your alert to work, place it right after `distanceKM=... / 1000;`. You'll also need special handling of end[i] . e.g.

```
    directionsService.route(request, (function(destination){ 
        return function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                distanceKM=response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
                alert(destination+distanceKM);
            }
        };
    })(request.destination));
```

This uses the [Immediately-invoked function expression(IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) pattern.

Comment: Thank a lot for the execution order!, but I think we are still missing something. The alert gives all the address "4800 Whitesburg Dr., Huntsville, AL, USA" seems its like the last value of the array

Comment: Also I notice it doesn't give the same result each time getting the distance, but I think I am passing an array value end[i], so the alert should always be in order

Comment: I am actually fine with whatever order it is alert, but as long as the address matches the distance

Comment: ah I see, will udpate

Comment: I actually just solved it, seems like the google destination variable doesn't like array, so I create a function with parameter address, thus google api destionation takes that single address and I just loop through that function total # addresses while passing respective address. Thanks though, without your help wouldn't have look at the destination variable

Comment: cool. do take a look at the IIFE link, it helps when you are trying to lock in a value used by a callback